# I want to use rewriterule to redirect this url to this url

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

http://domain.co.kr/areasearch?sfl=wr_7&stx=apple

I want to use rewriterule to redirect this url to this url

http://domain.co.kr/areasearch/wr_7/apple

I added the below rewriterule regex at the bottom

**RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ areasearch?sfl=$1&stx=$2 [QSA,L]**

When I access the url below, I get a **Not Found The requested URL /wr_7/apple was not found on this server.** What's the problem?

**http://domain.co.kr/areasearch/wr_7/apple**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^shop/list-([0-9a-z]+)$  shop/list.php?ca_id=$1&rewrite=1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/type-([0-9a-z]+)$  shop/listtype.php?type=$1&rewrite=1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+)$  shop/item.php?it_id=$1&rewrite=1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/([^/]+)/$  shop/item.php?it_seo_title=$1&rewrite=1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$  bbs/content.php?co_id=$1&rewrite=1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^content/([^/]+)/$  bbs/content.php?co_seo_title=$1&rewrite=1      [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^rss/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$  bbs/rss.php?bo_table=$1        [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$  bbs/board.php?bo_table=$1&rewrite=1      [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/([^/]+)/$ bbs/board.php?bo_table=$1&wr_seo_title=$2&rewrite=1      [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/write$  bbs/write.php?bo_table=$1&rewrite=1    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)/([0-9]+)$  bbs/board.php?bo_table=$1&wr_id=$2&rewrite=1  [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ areasearch?sfl=$1&stx=$2 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: "I want to use rewriterule to redirect this url to this URL" - Although the rule you are trying to implement does the complete opposite?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex (`^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$`) doesn't match `areasearch/wr_7/apple`

You probably missed that your URL starts with `areasearch/` so this should work

`^areasearch/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$`